# What is the bare minimum of packages necessary to build a Mono project?

Tags: ubuntu, mono

I'm using a netbook with a 4 GB solid state disk running Lubuntu. MonoDevelop takes too much space and pulls in many dependencies the project I want to build doesn't need. Namely, I only need .NET 2.0, WinForms, and VB.NET.

What is the bare minimum of packages necessary to build .sln, .vbproj, and associated code files into executables?

Comment: Why are you trying to build anything on a 4 GB solid state disk? Do you really intend to do significant dev work on this?

Comment: It's what I have. And with all the debt I'm in, I'd rather not spend on a new computer if I can.

Comment: Is there a specific project that you are trying to build? If it's something small, you may want to take a look at [scriptcs](https://github.com/scriptcs/scriptcs).